# После 4 итерации выдает -1#INF

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <math.h>


    using namespace std;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        float o, y, x , e , g,n, r;

        cin >> x >> e;
        y = 0;
        r = (x - 1);
        o = (x + 1);
        n = 0;
        while (n <= e)
        {
            y = (r / ((2*n+1)*o));
            r = r*r*r;
            o = o*o*o;
            n++;
            cout << y << endl;
        }
        g = 2 * y;
        cout << g << endl;
        cout << log(x);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Добрый вечер! При любых значениях x больше 2, после 4 итерации выдает -1#INF. Я так понимаю, что так происходит, потому что начинается деление на ноль. Но я не понимаю почему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

Comment: логируйте все переменные во всех итерациях и смотрите в консоли что пошло "не так"

Comment: Отладчик в помощь

Comment: Судя по `stdafx.h`, вы работаете в Visual Studio. У него превосходный встроенный отладчик. Откройте для себя клавиши F10 и F11, а также окошко Watch.

Comment: А если `float` на `double` заменить?

Answer (score 2):

Вы хоть прикиньте, что считаете.
После первого шага `r` и `o` возводятся в куб, после второго оказываются в 27 степени, после третьего - в 81... Понятно, что в переполнение/недополнение :) вы влетаете очень быстро...

Вот как по-хорошему должны выглядеть ваши расчеты:

```
int n;
float x;

cout << "Введите x и количество итераций: ";
cin >> x >> n;

float z = (x-1)/(x+1);
float t = z*z;
float sum = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    float y = z/(2*i+1);
    z *= t;
    sum += y;
   cout << y << endl;
}
sum *= 2;
cout << sum << endl;
cout << log(x);
```